# How to make 'testPattern' mandatory while updating snapshots in Jest?

Tags: jestjs

[Snapshot testing](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html) comes handy for testing UI components. If your UI component changes, you are expected to update the snapshot as well to reflect the same. We can specify 'testNamePattern' to update snapshots for a specific test.

```
jest --updateSnapshot --testNamePattern abc.test.js
```

Is it possible to mandate 'testNamePattern' while updating snapshots? This will help avoid updating other failing snapshots by mistake. I understand that it is expected to be caught in code review phase. However, I want to ensure that snapshots are always updated for a specific pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, there isn't any CLI option for doing this per [doc](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html). I have added a small snippet to my `testFrameworkScriptFile` to ensure that `testNamePattern` is passed while updating snapshots.

```js
import yargs from 'yargs';
const mandateTestNamePattern = () => {
    const args = yargs.option('testNamePattern', {
        type: 'string'
    }).option('t', {
        type: 'string'
    }).argv;

    if (args.updateSnapshot || args.u) {
        if (args.testNamePattern || args.t) {
            // valid case
        } else {
            throw new Error('TestNamePattern is mandatory while updating snapshots');
        }
    }
};

mandateTestNamePattern();
```